# Prendre garde : expression à plusieurs variantes

Tags: expressions, vocabulaire

Voici ce qu'a ma bible pour le verset Luc 21:8 :

[image: Prenez garde d'être séduits]

Naturellement pour moi en anglophone le sens semble être inversé ! "Take care to be deceived."

[D'autres traductions](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=luke%2021%3A8&version=LSG;BDS;NEG1979;SG21) sont d'accord, si on remarque que la « polarité » a changé :

> Prenez garde **que vous ne soyez pas séduits**.

De plus, le dictionnaire WordReference [donne](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/prendre%20garde) une autre variation encore :

> Prends garde **à ne pas tomber dans ce ravin**.

Ngrams indique que tous les trois existent, mais que « prendre garde à » l'emporte ([inf](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prendre%20garde%20de%2C%20prendre%20garde%20que%2C%20prendre%20garde%20%C3%A0&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2009&corpus=7&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprendre%20garde%20de%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprendre%20garde%20que%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprendre%20garde%20%C3%A0%3B%2Cc0), [2s](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prends%20garde%20de%2Cprends%20garde%20que%2Cprends%20garde%20%C3%A0&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=7&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cprends%20garde%20de%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bprends%20garde%20de%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPrends%20garde%20de%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cprends%20garde%20que%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bprends%20garde%20que%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPrends%20garde%20que%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cprends%20garde%20%C3%A0%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bprends%20garde%20%C3%A0%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPrends%20garde%20%C3%A0%3B%2Cc0), [2p](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prenez%20garde%20de%2Cprenez%20garde%20que%2Cprenez%20garde%20%C3%A0&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=7&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cprenez%20garde%20de%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bprenez%20garde%20de%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPrenez%20garde%20de%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cprenez%20garde%20que%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bprenez%20garde%20que%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPrenez%20garde%20que%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cprenez%20garde%20%C3%A0%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bprenez%20garde%20%C3%A0%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPrenez%20garde%20%C3%A0%3B%2Cc0)).

[image: prendre garde à, prendre garde de, prendre garde que]

Mais je m'intéresse surtout au sort de « prendre garde de » avec sa polarité singulière : « prendre garde de [faire] » au lieu de « prendre garde à ne **pas** [faire] ; que tu ne [fasses] **pas** ».

Cette expression s'emploie-t-elle encore ? Pourquoi selon vous l'aurait-t-on remplacée lors de la retraduction de Luc 21:8 ?

Comment: "prendre garde à" est plus courant parce qu'il peut être suivi d'un nom, contrairement aux deux autres.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'expression **prendre garde de** est effectivement ambiguë.

Certaines sources (TLFi, Dictionnaire des pièges difficultés de la langue française) indiquent qu'elle signifie ***éviter avec soin*** mais d'autres (OQLF) renvoient à la signification opposée ***avoir soin de***, ***veiller à***.

[TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/garde):

> Prendre garde de + inf. S'efforcer d'éviter de. Mais il faut prendre garde de s'amuser trop du scandale (Gide, Journal,1893, p. 40). Et surtout prenons garde de nous refroidir (A. France, Bergeret,1901, p. 349).

[OQLF](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4274) :

> L’expression prendre garde peut aussi être suivie de la préposition de et d’un infinitif. Elle signifie « avoir soin de », « veiller à ». L’infinitif qui suit peut être à la forme négative ou affirmative. C’est l’emploi avec un infinitif négatif qui semble maintenant le plus fréquent.
>
> Exemples :
>
> - J’ai pris garde de ne pas le blesser par mes paroles. (J’ai pris soin de ne pas le blesser par mes paroles.)
> - Prends garde de nous avertir si tu penses arriver en retard. (Veille à nous avertir si tu penses arriver en retard.)

---

Seul le contexte permet de distinguer le sens.

> - Prends garde de te faire écraser par la cavalerie (Le coin du feu, 1840)
> - Prends garde de ne pas te faire repérer (Dictionnaire du français langue étrangère CLE, le Robert, 2013)

Celui du TLFi semble plus littéraire et daté.

Answer (score 3):

Ah, les joies de la langue française...

Je suis tombé sur cette page après avoir lu l’île mystérieuse de Jules Verne. Lui-même utilise dans son roman les deux formes:

> Quant à ce feu, il fallait prendre garde de ne plus le laisser éteindre.
>   et
>
> En effet, répondit Pencroff, et prenons garde de tomber dans un trou.

Je n’utilisais que la première forme et était intrigué par la seconde.
En effet, comme cela a été écrit précédemment, c’est le contexte qui détermine le sens.