# How can "Prends garde" means "Be careful" or "Beware"?

Tags: expressions, prononciation, phrase

`Prends` means `to take`.

`Garde` means `to keep`

So how can `Prends` + `Garde` become `Be careful` or `Beware`?

Is it something like "Take and keep" that means that the person need to take all information and keep it for it self?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Garde*** has not the ***to keep*** meaning but the ***to guard*** one, so it's more like ***be on (your) guard*** (literally "take guard", i.e. take care, pay attention).

e.g.:

- *Prends garde à toi* (take care of you)

Beware that *prendre garde* often keeps the same meaning regardless of whether it is used negatively or positively.

See [Prendre garde : expression à plusieurs variantes](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/27650)

Answer (score 0):

`Garde` has several meanings https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/garde/36093

What interests us is the last definition :

> - En boxe, en escrime et dans les sports de combat, attitude que l'on prend pour engager le combat et se protéger.

Which means `Combat Position`.

You can understand `Prends garde` has `Take a position that allow you to defend yourself`.

Comment: While definitely related, the expression you describes is closer to ***en garde*** (starts a fight) than ***prends garde*** (pay attention, take care, there could be a danger).